# Remove duplicate file names from a listing, disregarding directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am running Linux and writing a BASH script.

I have a text file that has an absolute file path on each line. I have found that sometimes one of my text files will have an identical file but listed under a different path. I want to remove these lines that contain identical files such that the file is represented only once.

For instance, if I have:

```
/path/to/number1/file1.txt
/path/to/number1/file2.txt
/path/to/number1/file3.txt
/path/to/number2/file3.txt
```

I want the resulting file to contain:

```
/path/to/number1/file1.txt
/path/to/number1/file2.txt
/path/to/number1/file3.txt
```

The path length is variable (the file name cannot be guaranteed to be at field 4, for instance).

I have tried previous solutions to similar problems that use uniq, but uniq doesn't seem to provide an option to match the last field, nor does it allow one to set the delimiter. What are some solutions to this?

Comment: Your sample output does not match the description.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Perhaps what I said was confusing. I have many thousands of "file listings" that contain the absolute path of some files. Some of these listings were found to contain the same file, but under a different path (two identical files). I just want to remove one of these identical files from the list, it does not matter greatly which one is removed because they are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'/' '!a[$NF]++' file
```

- `-F'/'` - treating `/` as field separator
- `!a[$NF]++` - ensures output for only unique filenames (contained in the last column `$NF`)

The output:

```
/path/to/number1/file1.txt
/path/to/number1/file2.txt
/path/to/number1/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk, you could do:

```
awk -F\/ '{ path=""; if ( path1[$NF] == "" ) { print $0;path1[$NF]=$0 } }' filename
```

We build a variable path within awk. The filename is represented by $NF (the last field separated by /). We build an array of filenames (path1) with their associated paths. With each record/line in the file, this array is referenced to check if there is a path entry for the filename. If there is an entry, the record is ignored, hence stopping any duplication, otherwise the path is printed

Comment: You don't need all that work to build `path` since you only use `path$NF` which is exactly the same as `$0`.  Note `for(in)` can and almost always will produce the filenames in a different order than the input; it's not clear if that matters to this OP.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Order of the files actually does not matter in my case.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, you make a valid point and I have amended the code to simplify and take account of ordering.

Answer (score 1):

There's an expressive solution using pure bash built ins.

With associative arrays as sets, you can do it by continuously checking if the key is already being used, in which case you simply continue the loop.

```
# We will have a set which will contain existing filenames as keys.
declare -A fileSet

while read fullPath; do 
    fileName="${fullPath##*/}" # basename
    if [ ! -n "${fileSet[$fileName]}" ]; then # If the file is not already in the set.
        echo $fullPath >> $FILEOUTPUT
        fileSet[$fileName]=1
    fi
done < $FILEINPUT
```